# How to convert Excel macro enabled workbook for use on mobile phone?

Tags: excel, vba, mobile

I created a macro enabled workbook to enter information on the worksheet and to e-mail it.

I downloaded Excel for mobile but all macros are disabled.

Is there a way to make it so the workbook could be used on a mobile phone?

Comment: VBA is not running on mobile, see [Why can't I open my Excel file?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/why-can-t-i-open-my-excel-file-2daa6bd6-8db5-4521-9f37-7e23b3e4bdab?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#ID0EAABAAA=Android)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the VBA engine does not function on the mobile version of Excel. Macro-enabled Workbooks (.xlsx) will open, but the macros will not run. Macro-enabled Templates (.xltm) and Add-Ins (.xla and .xlam) won't even open.

See Microsoft's support article [Why can't I open my Excel File?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/why-can-t-i-open-my-excel-file-2daa6bd6-8db5-4521-9f37-7e23b3e4bdab?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#ID0EAABAAA=Android) for more information and a complete breakdown by file type and mobile OS.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: @TeachASU The lack of VBA-on-mobile is actually one of the reasons I bought a Surface 3 LTE initially (and later a Surface 5 with LTE). I wanted something portable, cell-data-enabled, and capable of running full-up Excel.